Error on iOS Simulator with .net MAUI app: The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion
I have an existing MAUI app that works on android and windows environments as expected, when trying to run the app on an iOS simulator, i get the following debug output on vs code:
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.

Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Simulator device failed to install the application.
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Failed to install the requested application
    The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
error HE0046: Failed to install the app '***' on the device 'iOS 17.2': simctl returned exit code 22

I have tried:
Resetting the simulator.
Testing on different devices.
Adding a CFBundleVersion.
Replicating the same resource folder structure/content on sample apps
Sample apps build and run without issues, so i have no idea what the issue could be...
Update: by request, this is the ApplicationDisplayVersion and ApplicationVersion in my app
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
<ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

this works in another sample project i have, and i have tried changing ApplicationDisplayVersion to have up to 3 dots (1.0.0.1) as well as changing ApplicationVersion to have up to 4 numbers (tried 1, 20, 301 and 4321 not sure if that matters...)

what is the value of CFBundleVersion?

Considering this is a maui app and you don't set the cfbundleversion manually, it should be pulling it from my application ID tag in my .csproj file, that's 1.0.0, fresh ios apps with the same configuration and same plist file run without an issue as mentioned above

Can you add the version number you're using from the .csproj? Something like:
1.1.03
1103

@tonyedwardspz done!

In the csproj file, did you add additional statements under <MauiAsset Include="ResourcesRaw**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"/>? Or did you have other resources in the Resources-> raw folder?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT i have the following: <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"/> and nothing else for resources -> raw

You can refer to this case: Cannot launch ios app on simulator or device with the same error as you, most of the reason is because some resources have been added to the project, and if you have added related resources, you can try to replace them and check if the error still occurs

You can check your project by following the steps below

Ensure the version settings in the project's csproj file match the
version in the info.plist file.
The Application Display Version in the csproj file matches the
Version in the info.plist file, and the Application Version
matches the Build.
You can refer to Information property list to learn about the
relationship between info.plist file and .csproj file.

According to the solution in the Cannot launch ios app on simulator
or device "does not contain valid CFBundleVersion", the problem
may not be caused by the version setting.
If relevant resources are added to the Resources folder of your
project, you can try to temporarily delete or replace them to check
whether the error will disappear.

Check whether all packages in the project have been successfully
added to the project, such as GoogleService-Info.This may also cause
your error


For other possible causes of the error, you can refer to the answer in The bundle's Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleVersion key. Many of the answers indicate that there are many reasons that can cause this error. You can try the solutions according to your project.
